# failing to read characters of string

Tags: c

there are 2 functions, first one to calculate weight of the word,second is to check which of the word has the most value and returns the address of it, my problem is whenever i make double pointer and insert values into it then "insert" that pointer to my function it fails to read the values in it.(not the best English sorry i tried my best)

it only works whenever copy my function in the main function and run it with loop, I'm still new so try to explain the problem and please try not to get mad if its stupid question!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int calc_weight(char* word);
char* max_weight(char* s[], int n);

int main()
{   
    char s[5][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        scanf("%s", (s + i));
    printf("%s\n",max_weight(s, 5));


    return 0;
}
int calc_weight(char* word)    //calculates weight of the word
{       //assuming this function gets only small letters a...z
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)// a=1,b=2...
        counter += word[i] - 'a' + 1;
    return counter;
}
char* max_weight(char* s[], int n)
{
    int maxind = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (calc_weight(s + i) > calc_weight(s + maxind))
            maxind = i;
    return (s+maxind);
}
```

Comment: don't call `strlen(word)` in the for loop. Save the result to a variable or `strlen` will be called each iteration which is a bad idea

Comment: what do you mean by: weight of a word?  what do you mean by: value of a word?  Please clarify

Comment: regarding: `counter += word[i] - 'a' + 1;`  what if the character is a capital letter?

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output a long string of warning messages.  When compiling,  always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", (s + i));` 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In this case any returned value other than 1 indicates an error.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]'  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte.  This also assure that the input buffer will not be overflowed, with the attendant undefined behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `max_weight` when you write `char* s[]` it means:

> declare s as array of pointer to char

but you are not passing an array of pointer.

Instead do `char s[][10]` like:

```
char* max_weight(char s[][10], int n)
```

to tell that `s` is a pointer to an array of 10 chars.